# Error when running form application with reference to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have a simple web service application, that has a reference to http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx

My main function in Service1.asmx.cs looks like this:

```
public com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherReturn HelloWorld( string zip) 
{
    com.cdyne.wsf.WeatherReturn x;
    com.cdyne.wsf.Weather w = new com.cdyne.wsf.Weather();
    x=w.GetCityWeatherByZIP(zip);
    return x;
}
```

I created a form, made reference to web service application (reference saved under a name "localhost") and called functin Hello world:

```
static void Main()
{
    localhost.Service1 service= new WeatherApplication.localhost.Service1();
    localhost.WeatherReturn a = service.HelloWorld("10001");
    Console.WriteLine(a);

    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

The code has no errors, web service runs and opens in browser but when I try to run form I get an error:

*Error when trying to run project:*

> Unable to start program

*here the location of my project is written.*

> The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

I don't even know what to try, I tried googling error, but haven't found anything applicable to this exact problem.